# Multiple return types in rust

Tags: rust

I have a library function `f1` in `rust` that returns a string and want to update it to optionally return a vector.

```
fn f1() -> String {
   "abc"
}

fn f2() -> (String, Vec<usize>) {
   "abc", vec![(0, 1, 2)]
}

fn f3(flag: bool) -> ? {
    if (flag)
        "abc", vec![(0, 1, 2)]
    else
        "abc"
}
```

Is it possible to have multiple return path like `f3`?

Comment: Why not return an empty vector in the `else` branch? Do you need to differentiate between "no vector" and "empty vector"? From my experience, this difference only causes head-aches in languages where everything is nullable.

Comment: You _could_ possibly use [std::option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) depending on what you're trying to achieve by doing optional returns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can return an enum:

```
enum StrOrStrAndVec<'a> {
    Str(&'a str),
    StrAndVec(&'a str, Vec<usize>),
}

fn f3(flag: bool) -> StrOrStrAndVec<'static> {
    if flag {
        StrOrStrAndVec::StrAndVec("abc", vec![0, 1, 2])
    } else {
        StrOrStrAndVec::Str("abc")
    }
}
```

The `either` crate simplifies this approach:

```
use either::*;

fn f3(flag: bool) -> Either<&'static str, (&'static str, Vec<usize>)> {
    if flag {
        Right(("abc", vec![0, 1, 2]))
    } else {
        Left("abc")
    }
}
```

Or, in this case you can use an `Option`:

```
fn f3(flag: bool) -> (&'static str, Option<Vec<usize>>) {
    if flag {
        ("abc", Some(vec![0, 1, 2]))
    } else {
        ("abc", None)
    }
}
```

However, since `Vec::new()` doesn't allocate memory, returning an empty `Vec` is similarly efficient:

```
fn f3(flag: bool) -> (&'static str, Vec<usize>) {
    if flag {
        ("abc", vec![0, 1, 2])
    } else {
        ("abc", Vec::new())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed6e7caeb983ac052b98ae5a20aad9fc)

Comment: The `either` crate is useful!